# $f''$ must be constant if $f(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}})+f(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}})=g(x)+h(y)$

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm trying to understand why for a real-valued smooth function f, the condition

$$
f\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)
 + f\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2}\right)
 = g(x) + h(y)
$$
must imply
$$
f''\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)
 = f''\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2}\right) \quad \forall (x,y)
$$

That would be obvious if $h''=0$, but in general I don't see it.

(This is part of the proof of sharp young inequality, in the part where optimizers are shown to be Gaussian functions in the book "Analysis" by Lieb and Loss.)

I guess it should be easy, but I'm kinda stuck here, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you take $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}$ of both sides, the right-hand side zeroes out and the second term on the LHS reverses sign.